# CakePHP Media Plugin version 1.3, UUID filenames

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is anybody else using [David Persson's media plugin for CakePHP](http://www.ohloh.net/p/cakephp-media)? I'm struggling with setting up some features of the latest version. I'd like to set it up to make a UUID-based filename for uploaded images, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

I will fight with it some more, but I'm posting to find out if anybody here can tell me if the 1.3 is generally working or generally NOT working.

Comment: somebody over at the google group for cakephp informed me that he's using this with cake 1.3. i'm still figuring it out though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got this (partially) working. The UUID filename stuff works when I place the following code in my Attachment model:

```
function transferTo($via, $from) {
    extract($from);
    $irregular = array(
        'image' => 'img',
        'text' => 'txt'
    );
    $name = Mime_Type::guessName($mimeType ? $mimeType : $file);
    if (isset($irregular[$name])) {
        $short = $irregular[$name];
    } else {
        $short = substr($name, 0, 3);
    }
    $path  = $short . DS;
    $path .= String::uuid();
    $path .= !empty($extension) ? '.' . strtolower($extension) : null;
    return $path;
}
```

I'm still having some trouble with other parts of the Media Helper, but the author posted some updates to his git repository today (Jul 17 2010).

Comment: i got pretty close, it did MOSTLY work out-of-the-box. in the end i switched to a different solution. i've noticed that the author has updated MediaHelper since then, so you might give it a try.